# Need Help Maintaining Swift Environment Object

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to place a SwiftUI View into a ViewController using UIHostingController, but receiving the following error:

*No ObservableObject of type UIStateModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for UIStateModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.*

All help appreciated, I've been quite stuck :(.

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @EnvironmentObject var UIModel: UIStateModel
    var uiState: UIStateModel = UIStateModel()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addCarousel()
    }
    
    func addCarousel(){
        let snapC : SnapCarousel
        let contentView : UIHostingController<SnapCarousel>
        uiState = UIStateModel()
        snapC = SnapCarousel( UIState: uiState )
        contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: snapC)
        addChild(contentView)
        view.addSubview(contentView.view)
        contentView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
}
```

Carousel.swift

```
struct SnapCarousel: View {
    var UIState: UIStateModel
    //Carousel instantiation 
}

struct Card: Decodable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    //code
}

public class UIStateModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activeCard: Int = 0
    @Published var screenDrag: Float = 0.0
}

struct Carousel<Items : View> : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var UIState: UIStateModel
    //card management
}

struct Canvas<Content : View> : View {
// view manager 
}

struct Item<Content: View>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var UIState: UIStateModel
   //code for card view
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI wrappers that inherit [DynamicProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty) do not work in a `class` you can't use `@EnvironmentObject` in a `UIViewController`. You can create it and pass it but you have to manually subscribe to changes using `.sink`

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `UIStateModel` as an `@EnvironmentObject` so that it can be injected automatically in the subviews.

First, update `SnapCarousel` to hold the environmentObject:

```
struct SnapCarousel: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var UIState: UIStateModel
    //Carousel instantiation 
}
```

To register model as environment object, when register with `SnapCarousel` as:

```
let snapC = SnapCarousel()
snapC.environmentObject(uiState)
```

If you don't need a reference to `uiState`, you can simplify the whole thing to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addCarousel()
  }

  func addCarousel() {
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SnapCarousel().environmentObject(UIStateModel()))
    addChild(controller)
    view.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    
    // add some constraints to fill the parent view
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      controller.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
      controller.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
      controller.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      controller.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
  }
}
```